# MySQL is not connecting

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, connector

DB and table names are correct. linked the classpath of MySQL connecter java. but when i run i get Not Found Result. i have tried different queries and different links to sql connector.

```
final static String jdbc_driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    final static String db_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/oyutan/";
    Connection con=null;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r) {
        if(r.getSource()==ok){
            fr.setVisible(false);
            GUI guu=new GUI();
            String card=cardnum.getText();
            String pinn=pin.getText();

            String sql="SELECT *FROM `card`";
            try{
                Class.forName(jdbc_driver);
                con=DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, "root", "");
                ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next());{
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("")+"");
                }}

                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Not Found!");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you can do like e.getMessage or something to get more info on the exception?

Comment: Your SQL doesn't look right there...

Comment: Don't quote your table

Comment: according to your question MySQL is not connection, what the exception throw by JVM when you trying to connect ?

Comment: I feel the port is missing in db url

Comment: try putting a space between * and from. If that doesn't work, then try unquoting your table name

Comment: Can you print the stack trace

Comment: Why the comments to remove quotes? Quoting is perfectly valid and is applied to be able to have table names with keywords or 'strange characters'. The fact that quoting is not needed here is besides the point.

Comment: I am getting "Communications link failure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no space between * And  FROM , try using this :

```
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM 'card' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
String sql="SELECT *FROM `card`";
```

to

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM card ";
```

and give a try

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake you must add the portnumber after localhost. in db_url

ex :- `final static String db_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/oyutan/";` modify this as
       `final static String db_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:<port number>/oyutan/";`

without the port number it wont work.
the port number is not always the same it could be 3306,3309 etc..

```
final static String db_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oyutan/";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your sql was wrong.

```
  String sql="SELECT * FROM card ";
```

you need add a white space after " * "